# Assign a task with due date on item creation

Tags: workflow, list, tasks

I have a discussion board which has a field called as Reviewer which is a person field. I want that whenever a reviewer is added to the discussion, a new task / reminder should get added with a due date of 7 days and a mail should be sent. If he does not reply in 7 days, another reminder mail should go. I tried to do this by assigning a task to him with the title of discussion thread. But am facing issues assigning a due date to the task.

Is there any other way or idea for doing the same?

Comment: How did you assign the task to him? Are you trying a workflow? in SharePoint designer or visual studio?

Comment: I am trying to use a workflow in sharepoint designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a workflow that fires on Item creation in the Discussion list to create a task a Task list.  The task list would have an on creation workflow that pauses for 7 days.  Then in the next step, look to see if the task is complete, if it isn't it emails the assigned to person.

Comment: I tried to create task on item creation / as soon as reviewer is added. But am not able to add a due date to it. Can u please provide a step by step procedure to do this. Any blog post / article would also be helpful.